# Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:

Tags: reactjs, next.js, aws-amplify

I have a NextJS React app on AWS Amplify. Im trying to use Stripe, but everything is getting pretty messed up because of my Content Security Policy (CSP) settings. I'm not able to change them for some reason. I've tried making changes to Next.config.js, I've used the header insertion tool in AWS Amplify, and I've also tried adding `<Meta>` tags in my React code itself. I still get this error no matter what I do.

What is left to debug this?

```
Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-1bd1ss83rhoRESXnUSD+xUzVPZzKrKQPYKkWOj5TJIc='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present.
```

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
module.exports = {
    async headers() {
      return [
        {
          source: '/:path*',
          headers: [
            {
              key: 'Content-Security-Policy',
              value: "style-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' js.stripe.com accounts.google.com clarity.ms www.clarity.ms 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'",
            },
          ],
        },
      ]
    },
  }
```

Comment: "stripe" what there are multiple tags even here for "stripe"

Comment: Is there any `meta` tag on the page that already defines a CSP which you've overlooked?

Comment: @Slbox - Unless they are being generated by React, and override next.config.js, I'm not seeing them.

Comment: If they could take effect, you'd see them. Have you verified that the headers actually reflect your config? You can see the defined response headers in the `Network` tab of devtools.

Comment: @Slbox yes I just checked the network request for main-app.js, and it does show the CSP rules I defined in next.config.js (same ones posted in my original post). But I'm still getting this error.

Comment: Update: Actually, no - They appear in development mode, but in production on Amplify, they disappear!! How do I fix this?

Comment: Unsure but I'd advise highlighting that issue in the question text.